# Error creating AddOrUpdate stored procedure with a list type

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, merge

Trying to bulk insert or update stored procedure that will run efficient and quick for big record set.

I believe using the merge function in a stored procedure would probably be the quickest way for bulk insert or update.

However, I'm running into an error when trying to compile the stored procedure, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm getting the following error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Here's the sample code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.procedures WHERE name = 'AddOrUpdateRecords')
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE AddOrUpdateRecords;
    PRINT 'Drop AddOrUpdateRecords Stored Procedure'
END
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'RecordList')
BEGIN
    DROP TYPE RecordList;
    PRINT 'Drop RecordList Type';
END
GO

CREATE TYPE RecordList
AS TABLE
(
    Code varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Name varchar(max) NOT NULL,
    GeneratedDate date NULL
);
GO

PRINT 'Created RecordList Type';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE AddOrUpdateRecords
    @List AS RecordList READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE dbo.Records AS tgt
    USING @List AS src
    ON tgt.Code = src.Code
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET tgt.Name = src.Name, tgt.GeneratedDate = src.GeneratedDate
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES(src.Code, src.Name, src.GeneratedDate);
END
GO

PRINT 'Created AddOrUpdateRecords Stored Procedure';
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your [not matched] case you need to specify the columns that are assigned values in the insert statement. e.g.,

```
when not matched then 
    insert (col1, col2, col3) 
    values (src.Code, src.Name, src.GeneratedDate);
```

Comment: Thank you!  That's it! 

I've tried that before with tgt. prefix and it generated a different error.  I forgot to try it without the prefix.

And the error was pointing to the table line, so it mislead me to believe I did something wrong on top.